Minimizing the resultant of two vectors where one vector is magnified by some $b$
Consider two vectors $\vec{r},\vec{s}$ in $ℝ^3$ with a constant $b$ chosen such that the length of the resultant $\vec{r}$ and $b\vec{s}$ is minimum. Prove that this occurs when $(\vec{r}+b\vec{s}),b\vec{s},$ and $\vec{r}$ form a right angled triangle.
My method of solution:
$|\vec{r}+b\vec{s}|^2=b^2|\vec{s}|^2+b(2\vec{r}.\vec{s})+|\vec{r}|^2$
So, the length of the resultant vector is a quadratic in $b$ which is minimum when $b=-\dfrac{\vec{r}.\vec{s}}{|\vec{s}|^2}$.
At this value, the expression becomes; $|\vec{r}+b\vec{s}|^2=\dfrac{|\vec{r}|^2|\vec{s}|^2-(\vec{r}.\vec{s})^2}{|\vec{s}|^2} \implies|(\vec{r}+b\vec{s}) \times \vec{s}|^2=|\vec{r}+b\vec{s}|^2|\vec{s}|^2$
which indicates that $(\vec{r}+b\vec{s})$ and $b\vec{s}$ are perpendicular.
Hence, $|\vec{r}+b\vec{s}|^2+|b\vec{s}|^2=|\vec{r}|^2+2b^2|\vec{s}|^2+2b(\vec{r}.\vec{s})=|\vec{r}|^2 $which is the statement of the Pythagoras theorem for the triangle thus verifying the right-angled triangle.
I'm looking for a proof involving more geometric intuition perhaps relying on some clever use of vector addition and circles that I've seen used in physics for maximizing and minimizing vector resultants, or even just an illuminating figure illustrating why this result is obvious. Can anyone help me out?

Consider $\vec r + b \vec s$ to be the parametric equation of a line through $\vec r$ with direction vector $\vec s$
$|\vec r + b \vec s|$ is minimized when it follows the shortest path connecting the line to the origin (that path being perpendicular to the direction vector $\vec s$)
A desmos graph visualization ...
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/myemeezis0

there is a slight ambiguity regarding the triangle formed by the vectors $ \vec r, (\vec{r}+b\vec{s})\text{ and }b\vec{s}$, but I think we can accept that the green triangle is intended.

How is there ambiguity? Is the problem not misstated?

I should have added negative sign to $\vec{r}+b\vec{s}$ so that their sum is $0$, sorry
